# sum up objects of a list

Tags: python, list, sum

i'm writing a code that should take in a filename and create an initial list. Then, i'm trying to sum up each item in the list. The code i've written so far looks something like this...

```
filename = input('Enter filename: ')
    Lists = []
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.strip().split()
        Lists = line
    print(Lists)
    total = 0
    for i in Lists:
        total = sum(int(Lists[i]))
    print(total)
```

I take in a filename and set all the objects in the line = to the List. Then, I make a variable total which should print out the total of each item in the list. For instance, if List = [1,2,3] then the total will be 6. However, is it possible to append integer objects to a list? The error i'm receiving is...

```
File "/Users/sps329/Desktop/testss copy 2.py", line 10, in main
    total = sum(int(Lists[i]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Something like this doesn't work also because the items in the List are strings and not numbers. Would I have to implement the function isdigit even though I know the input file will always be integers?...

```
total = sum(i)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Instead of

   ```
   Lists = line
   ```

   you need

   ```
   Lists.append(line)
   ```
2. You can get the total sum like this

   ```
   total = sum(sum(map(int, item)) for item in Lists)
   ```
3. If you dont want to create list of lists, you can use `extend` function

   ```
   Lists.extend(line)
   ...
   total = sum(map(int, Lists))
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response because it works. However, I had a few questions. If I append line to Lists, I would get a list within a list which I don't want. I just want a List. Similarly, I have never learned about the function map before. I'll read up on the function but would you have a method that is more "beginner" friendly?

Comment: @user2933041 Then, you can do, `Lists.extend(line)` and the total can be found with `sum(map(int, Lists))`. `map` is one of the basic functions in Python :)

Answer (score 2):

```
# creates a list of the lines in the file and closes the file
with open(filename) as f:
    Lists = f.readlines()

# just in case, perhaps not necessary
Lists = [i.strip() for i in Lists]

# convert all elements of Lists to ints
int_list = [int(i) for i in Lists]

# sum elements of Lists
total = sum(int_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print sum([float(x.strip()) for x in open(filename)])
```